# What can we know about the fixed points of the action of a strongly continuos one-parameter subgroup of unitary operators?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, quantum-mechanics

My motivation is physical, but my question in mathematical. In quantum mechanics, time evolution of states is the action of a one-parameter subgroup of projective-unitary transformations of a projective Hilbert space, $\mathcal P(\mathcal H)$. Stationary states are the fixed-points of the action of this one-parameter subgroup.

By Wigner's theorem this one-parameter group can be lifted to a strongly continuous one-parameter subgroup of the unitary group. The action of this one-parameter subgroup on $\mathcal H$ is described by the Schrödinger equation. Stationary state vectors are such eleents of $\mathcal H$ that remain in a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$ under this action. These one-dimensional subspaces are the stationary states in $\mathcal P(\mathcal H)$. In many important cases, stationary state vectors form a basis of $\mathcal H$, so the trajectory of any element of $\mathcal H$ is the linear combination of the trajectories of stationary states. Specifically, the fixed points of the acion of this strongly continuous one-parameter subgroup of unitary operators are also stationary state vectors, but they clearly cannot form a basis except when this one-parameter subgroup is trivial. In the non-trivial cases, what can we know about these fixed points?

Comment: I don't understand the second-to-last sentence, but the fixed points are eigenvectors of the generator of the one-parameter subgroup. In general there may not be any of these, e.g. consider translation acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This is the subject of the spectral theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In the sentence starting with "Specifically", I wanted to say that the linear combination of fixed vectors are also fixed, so they are "less useful" in describing a process then the non-fixed stationary state vectors. My question is aimed at these less useful state vectors.

Comment: So you're asking about the energy eigenstates with eigenvalue zero? What do you want to know about them? In general there may not be any.

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in how many there can be. In the trivial case, they are the whole $\mathcal H$, and as you said, they may not be none at all. Is there some rule for them between the two extreme cases?

Comment: The zero eigenspace can be any closed subspace $H'$ of $H$. You can take the one-parameter subgroup to be $e^{itA}$ where $A$ is the projection onto the orthogonal complement of $H'$.

Comment: Really, thank you. This is the answer.